# How can i set character limit in flutter quill editor

Tags: flutter, dart, quill

I am using flutter Quill Editor , and want to limit the user to enter maximum 1000 char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it by attaching listener and changing the document the following way:

in initState for example:

```dart
widget.quillController.document.changes.listen(_onDocumentChange)
```

somewhere in class:

```dart
void _onDocumentChange(Tuple3<quill.Delta, quill.Delta, quill.ChangeSource> tuple) {
    final documentLength = widget.quillController.document.length;
    if (documentLength > widget.limit) {
      final latestIndex = widget.limit - 1;
      widget.quillController.replaceText(
        latestIndex,
        documentLength - widget.limit,
        '',
        TextSelection.collapsed(offset: latestIndex),
      );
    }
 }
```